# Is it possible to create a license that allows user to use offline Electron application for certain number of times?

Tags: angular, electron, license-key

I was wondering if there is a way that allows user to use my offline electron app for certain number of times? I searched the internet but could not found anything related to it.

Comment: Is this a license question or a question about how to implement such a feature in code?

Comment: Thank You for the reply. This was a naive question back then.I have already solved this problem.